# datetime.strptime unable to render xcom variable

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have this simple dag with two tasks, one which returns a `datetime` as `str` and another which uses that to run TimeSensorAsync deferred operator.

```py
    @task
    def get_scheduled_upgrade_time(data: dict) -> str:
        return str(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=60))


    wait = TimeSensorAsync(task_id="waiting_until_scheduled_time", target_time=(datetime.strptime("{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_scheduled_upgrade_time', key='return_value') }}", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").time()))
```

I'm getting the following error in the Airflow UI:-

```
ValueError: time data "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_scheduled_upgrade_time') }}" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to manipulate datetime string as Jinja Template you need to use macros

You can not run functions on Jinja cause once the parsing is running on it, its actually run the function and its value is wrong.

replace your target_time with the following :

```
target_time = "{{ macros.datetime.strptime(task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_scheduled_upgrade_time', key='return_value'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').time() }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute `datetime.strptime` at the parsing time of the DAG file but it doesnt understand `Jinja` templating, also `TimeSensorAsync` operator takes a `datetime` object as a `target_time`, not a string, and `task_instance.xcom_pull` in Jinja templating is going to return a string, thats not going to work.

lets return `datetime` object directly, then use that in the `TimeSensorAsync` operator.

```
@task
def get_scheduled_upgrade_time(data: dict) -> datetime:
    return datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=60)

wait = TimeSensorAsync(task_id="waiting_until_scheduled_time", target_time="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_scheduled_upgrade_time', key='return_value') }}")
```

Comment: It seems you cannot return native datetime objects. It should be json-serializable.

Comment: Then we could try to create another task to convert the string datetime back to a datetime, we use TimeSensorAsync in this task.